Implementation Google Oauth in Vite + React with API of Laravel 11 with Sanctum Authentication
Has anyone here experienced implementing Google OAuth with Sanctum authentication? I’m looking for guidance or insights on how to achieve this.
I'm working on a project where I need to integrate Google OAuth for user authentication while using Sanctum for API token management. I’m familiar with both technologies separately but unsure of how to combine them effectively. Specifically, I need help with:
Setting up Google OAuth in a Laravel 11 application, including configuring the necessary credentials and callback URLs.
Integrating Sanctum to handle API token management and ensuring that Sanctum works with the tokens provided by Google OAuth.
Implementing secure user sessions and API request handling with both Google OAuth and Sanctum in place.
I’ve tried various approaches but haven’t found a clear guide that covers both technologies together. If anyone has experience or can share detailed steps, code examples, or resources that could help me implement this setup correctly, I would greatly appreciate it. Any best practices or pitfalls to avoid would also be very helpful.
